# VBA How to make a nested loop faster

Tags: excel, vba, loops, lag

I have created a macro that takes raw data from one sheet, and converts it into sumifs formulas in 19 other sheets. The problem is each column iteration takes about 1 minute to complete. What can I do to make the main bottle neck of the code faster?

```
'Units (Bottle Neck)
Dim B(), totalsum As Double, refnum As Integer, x As Integer
ReDim B(1 To 254, 1 To nr)
counter = 1
refnum = 1

For x = 39 To 51
    For snum = 1 To 19
        For refnum = 1 To 254
                For i = 3 To nr
                    If Left(A(i, 4), 5) = sorter(snum) And A(i, 5) = "2022" And A(i, 10) = Sheets(sorter(snum)).Cells(refnum + 5, 3) Then
                        B(refnum, counter) = A(i, x)
                        counter = counter + 1
                    End If
                Next i
                counter = 1
        Next refnum
            refnum = 1
            For refnum = 1 To UBound(B)
                For i = LBound(B) To UBound(B)
                    totalsum = totalsum + B(refnum, i)
                Next i
                Sheets(sorter(snum)).Cells(refnum + 5, x + 3) = totalsum
                totalsum = 0
            Next refnum
    Next snum
Next x
Erase B
```

Here is the script in entirety...

```
Option Explicit
Option Base 1

Sub CBKdump()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Application.EnableEvents = False

Dim A(), nr As Long, nc As Integer, i As Long, j As Integer, item As Variant
Dim Dictionary As Object, sheetName As String, ws As Worksheet, Dict As Object, counter As Integer
Dim starttime As Double, endtime As Double

'timer
starttime = Timer

Sheets("CBK200 Raw Data").Select
nr = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(2, 1).End(xlDown))) + 1
nc = Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(2, 1).End(xlToRight)).Columns.Count

'CBK Array A()
ReDim A(3 To nr, 1 To nc)

For i = 3 To nr
    For j = 1 To nc
        On Error Resume Next
        On Error GoTo 0
        If Not IsError(Cells(i, j)) Then
            A(i, j) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Trim(Cells(i, j))
        Else
            A(i, j) = ""
        End If
    Next j
Next i

'find sheet name
Set Dictionary = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
For i = 3 To UBound(A)
    If Not IsEmpty(A(i, 4)) And Not Dictionary.Exists(A(i, 4)) Then
        Dictionary.Add A(i, 4), Nothing
    End If
Next i

'Dict to array
i = 1
For Each item In Dictionary
    Dim sorter(), s As Variant
    ReDim Preserve sorter(1 To Dictionary.Count)
    sorter(i) = Left(item, 5)
    i = i + 1
Next item

'reverse array & create pages
Dim sorted()
For i = UBound(sorter) To 1 Step -1
    ReDim Preserve sorted(1 To UBound(sorter))
    sorted(i) = sorter(i)
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add
    ws.Name = sorter(i)
Next i

'reorganize cbk and all orgs
Sheets("All Orgs").Move Before:=Sheets(5)
Sheets("CBK200 Raw Data").Move Before:=Sheets(5)

'===============Resource Unit=====================

'open itrack workbook
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim filePath As String
filePath = "C:\Users\E100676\Documents\Billy\Backup\iTrack_Resource.xlsx"
Set wb = Workbooks.Open(filePath)

'add itrack wb data to array
Workbooks("iTrack_Resource").Sheets(1).Select
Dim inr As Integer, t(), snum As Integer
inr = Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(2, 1).End(xlDown)).Rows.Count
ReDim t(inr, 2)

For snum = 1 To UBound(sorter)
    For i = 2 To inr + 1
        For j = 1 To 2
            t(i - 1, j) = Trim(Cells(i, j))
        Next j
    Next i
Next snum

wb.Close SaveChanges:=False

'arrange by t array
Workbooks("Budget Test Sheet").Activate

For snum = 1 To UBound(sorter)
    For i = 6 To UBound(t)
        Sheets(sorter(snum)).Cells(i, 2) = t(i - 5, 1)
        Sheets(sorter(snum)).Cells(i, 3) = t(i - 5, 2)
        Sheets(sorter(snum)).Columns("P:AO").Hidden = True
    Next i
Next snum

'GL Account
For snum = 1 To UBound(sorter)
    For i = 6 To Sheets(sorter(snum)).Cells(6, 2).End(xlDown).Row
        If Sheets(sorter(snum)).Cells(i, 2) = 1 Then
            Sheets(sorter(snum)).Cells(i, 4) = 52734
        ElseIf Sheets(sorter(snum)).Cells(i, 2) >= 2 And Sheets(sorter(snum)).Cells(i, 2) <= 26 Then
            Sheets(sorter(snum)).Cells(i, 4) = 52725
        ElseIf Sheets(sorter(snum)).Cells(i, 2) >= 27 And Sheets(sorter(snum)).Cells(i, 2) <= 52 Then
            Sheets(sorter(snum)).Cells(i, 4) = 52728
        ElseIf Sheets(sorter(snum)).Cells(i, 2) >= 53 And Sheets(sorter(snum)).Cells(i, 2) <= 89 Then
            Sheets(sorter(snum)).Cells(i, 4) = 52732
        ElseIf Sheets(sorter(snum)).Cells(i, 2) >= 90 And Sheets(sorter(snum)).Cells(i, 2) <= 188 Then
            Sheets(sorter(snum)).Cells(i, 4) = 52721
        ElseIf Sheets(sorter(snum)).Cells(i, 2) >= 189 And Sheets(sorter(snum)).Cells(i, 2) <= 245 Then
            Sheets(sorter(snum)).Cells(i, 4) = 52723
        ElseIf Sheets(sorter(snum)).Cells(i, 2) >= 246 And Sheets(sorter(snum)).Cells(i, 2) <= 252 Then
            Sheets(sorter(snum)).Cells(i, 4) = 52750
        ElseIf Sheets(sorter(snum)).Cells(i, 2) = 253 Then
            Sheets(sorter(snum)).Cells(i, 4) = 52723
        ElseIf Sheets(sorter(snum)).Cells(i, 2) = 254 Then
            Sheets(sorter(snum)).Cells(i, 4) = 52752
        End If
    Next i
Next snum



'Headers
For snum = 1 To UBound(sorter)
    With Sheets(sorter(snum))
        .Cells(1, 1) = "Year - Division - Low Org"
        .Cells(1, 2) = "Ref"
        .Cells(1, 3) = "Resource Unit"
        .Cells(1, 4) = "GL Account"
        .Cells(1, 5) = "Unit of Measure"
        .Cells(1, 6) = "Pricing"
        .Cells(1, 7) = "Resource Unit Fee"
        .Cells(1, 8) = "Full Year % Allocation"
        .Cells(1, 9) = "Units"
        .Cells(1, 10) = "2023 Units"
        .Cells(1, 11) = "2023 Amount"
        .Cells(1, 12) = "2022 Projected Units"
        .Cells(1, 13) = "2022 Projected Amount"
        .Cells(1, 14) = "Use"
        .Cells(1, 15) = "Usage"
        .Cells(1, 16) = "Next FY Units"
        .Cells(1, 17) = "Jul Units"
        .Cells(1, 18) = "Aug Units"
        .Cells(1, 19) = "Sep Units"
        .Cells(1, 20) = "Oct Units"
        .Cells(1, 21) = "Nov Units"
        .Cells(1, 22) = "Dec Units"
        .Cells(1, 23) = "Jan Units"
        .Cells(1, 24) = "Feb Units"
        .Cells(1, 25) = "Mar Units"
        .Cells(1, 26) = "Apr Units"
        .Cells(1, 27) = "May Units"
        .Cells(1, 28) = "Jun Units"
        .Cells(1, 29) = "Next Fy $"
        .Cells(1, 30) = "Jul $"
        .Cells(1, 31) = "Aug $"
        .Cells(1, 32) = "Sep $"
        .Cells(1, 33) = "Oct $"
        .Cells(1, 34) = "Nov $"
        .Cells(1, 35) = "Dec $"
        .Cells(1, 36) = "Jan $"
        .Cells(1, 37) = "Feb $"
        .Cells(1, 38) = "Mar $"
        .Cells(1, 39) = "Apr $"
        .Cells(1, 40) = "May $"
        .Cells(1, 41) = "Jun $"
        .Cells(1, 42) = "Current Actuals YTD Units"
        .Cells(1, 43) = "Jul Units"
        .Cells(1, 44) = "Aug Units"
        .Cells(1, 45) = "Sep Units"
        .Cells(1, 46) = "Oct Units"
        .Cells(1, 47) = "Nov Units"
        .Cells(1, 48) = "Dec Units"
        .Cells(1, 49) = "Jan Units"
        .Cells(1, 50) = "Feb Units"
        .Cells(1, 51) = "Mar Units"
        .Cells(1, 52) = "Apr Units"
        .Cells(1, 53) = "May Units"
        .Cells(1, 54) = "Jun Units"
        .Cells(1, 55) = "Current Actuals YTD $"
        .Cells(1, 56) = "Jul $"
        .Cells(1, 57) = "Aug $"
        .Cells(1, 58) = "Sep $"
        .Cells(1, 59) = "Oct $"
        .Cells(1, 60) = "Nov $"
        .Cells(1, 61) = "Dec $"
        .Cells(1, 62) = "Jan $"
        .Cells(1, 63) = "Feb $"
        .Cells(1, 64) = "Mar $"
        .Cells(1, 65) = "Apr $"
        .Cells(1, 66) = "May $"
        .Cells(1, 67) = "Jun $"
        .Cells(1, 68) = "Current FY Budgeted Units"
        .Cells(1, 69) = "Current FY Budgeted $"
        .Cells(1, 70) = "Compare Units"
        .Cells(1, 71) = "Compare $"
    End With
    With Sheets(sorter(snum)).Range("A1:BS1")
        .Borders(xlEdgeBottom).Weight = xlThin
        .RowHeight = 45
    End With
    Sheets(sorter(snum)).Range("J1:M1").Interior.Color = RGB(226, 239, 218)
Next snum

'Units (Bottle Neck)
Dim B(), totalsum As Double, refnum As Integer, x As Integer
ReDim B(1 To 254, 1 To nr)
counter = 1
refnum = 1

For x = 39 To 51
    For snum = 1 To 19
        For refnum = 1 To 254
                For i = 3 To nr
                    If Left(A(i, 4), 5) = sorter(snum) And A(i, 5) = "2022" And A(i, 10) = Sheets(sorter(snum)).Cells(refnum + 5, 3) Then
                        B(refnum, counter) = A(i, x)
                        counter = counter + 1
                    End If
                Next i
                counter = 1
        Next refnum
            refnum = 1
            For refnum = 1 To UBound(B)
                For i = LBound(B) To UBound(B)
                    totalsum = totalsum + B(refnum, i)
                Next i
                Sheets(sorter(snum)).Cells(refnum + 5, x + 3) = totalsum
                totalsum = 0
            Next refnum
    Next snum
Next x
Erase B

'end time
endtime = Timer - starttime
Debug.Print endtime

'Amounts
ReDim B(1 To 254, 1 To nr)
counter = 1
refnum = 1

For x = 26 To 38
    For snum = 1 To 19
        For refnum = 1 To 254
                For i = 3 To nr
                    If Left(A(i, 4), 5) = sorter(snum) And A(i, 5) = "2022" And A(i, 10) = Sheets(sorter(snum)).Cells(refnum + 5, 3) Then
                            B(refnum, counter) = A(i, x)
                            counter = counter + 1
                    End If
                Next i
                counter = 1
        Next refnum
            refnum = 1
            For refnum = 1 To UBound(B)
                For i = LBound(B) To UBound(B)
                    totalsum = totalsum + B(refnum, i)
                Next i
                Sheets(sorter(snum)).Cells(refnum + 5, x + 29) = totalsum
                totalsum = 0
            Next refnum
    Next snum
Next x

'add years
For snum = 1 To 19
    Sheets(sorter(snum)).Cells(5, 1) = sorter(snum)
    Columns("AP:BB").NumberFormat = "0.00"
    Columns("BC:BS").NumberFormat = "_($* #,##0.00_);_($* (#,##0.00);_($* ""-""??_);_(@_)"
Next snum




Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

I've tried reducing the number of Loops, but I've found I need different counters. The NR is about 35,000 rows. As you can see at the bottleneck, it runs through each cell and creates a sumifs formula, but with 254 rows, 56 columns, and 19 sheets, that's 270,256 sumifs formulas being created. Please help Stack Overflow, you're my only hope.

Comment: Require a more thorough inspection, the ReDim Preserve stands out.  Appears a hell of a lot of ReDim Preserve slowing things down.  Possibly replace the arrays with a more appropriate data structure eg. Collection or maybe an ArrayList.   Early binding for Scripting.Dictionary will also improve performance.

Comment: For 'CBK Array A()  
On Error Resume Next
On Error GoTo 0 'Stop code and display error

Doesn't look right usually for a Try/Catch block expecting, On Error Resume Next some code to try, test if no error occured perform any actions, else catch the error then reset the error handler.

Comment: In that `'GL Account` section how many times does your code read the value from `Sheets(sorter(snum)).Cells(i, 2)` ?  Read that into a variable first, then test that...

Comment: `ReDim Preserve sorter(1 To Dictionary.Count)` no need to do this inside the loop - you're not changing the bounds of the array, just recreating it on each iteration.

Answer (score 0):

You are looping a lot more than you need to.

Imagine a class were you would make one instance per sheet (`snum`) that had methods to ingest information, then write it. Therefore, each instance could have its own arrays, counters, etc, without tripping each other up.

Now imagine a dictionary of these objects.

Now imagine a function where you pass a range that is a row, like

```vb
Set sht = Sheets("CBK200 Raw Data")
Set FirstCell = Cells(2, 1)
Set LastCell = FirstCell.End(xlDown).End(xlToRight)
Set rng = sht.Range(FirstCell, LastCell)
For Each rw In rng.Rows
  Ingest DictionaryOfSheetControllers, rw
Next
```

Where `Ingest` is

```vb
Sub Ingest(DictionaryOfSheetControllers, rw as Range)
  Dim SheetNameCell as Range

  SheetNameCell = rw.Cells(1, 4)
  Set controller = GetSheetController(DictionaryOfSheetControllers, SheetNameCell)
  If Not controller Is Nothing Then
    controller.ImportRawRow(rw)
  End Of
End Sub
```

Where `GetSheetController` either

- returns an existing SheetController from `DictionaryOfSheetControllers`,
- creates a new SheetController, adds it to `DictionaryOfSheetControllers` and returns it, or
- returns `Nothing` if the road shouldn't be added to any sheet.

In this way you're looping through your input rows exactly once. You are not creating the `A` array at all, You are not trimming values that you didn't need to trim, You don't need to loop through your data just to get all of the sheet names first because you are creating new sheet names on the fly, etc

Then, once you've imported all the rows, you can loop through your dictionary and call a method to output the results.

Comment: Thank you! Repopulating the array for each sheet will dramatically reduce the time it takes to loop.

Comment: You're welcome. Yes, and isolate state to prevent bugs. For example, if sheet 1 has more rows, then I'm pretty sure that affects the numbers on the other sheets because your code sums all in `B` but you don't clear it out between sheets.

Answer (score 0):

Use a jagged array (a 1D array where each element is a 2D array) and a resource dictionary then scan the rawdata sheet once summating the appropriate element. The resource dictionary is to translate the name to a number. Should run in less than 10 seconds for 24,130 lines of raw data.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub CBKdump2()

    Const RAWDATA = "CBK200 Raw Data"
    Const RESPATH = "" '"C:\Users\E100676\Documents\Billy\Backup\"
    Const RESFILE = "iTrack_Resource_Test.xlsx"
    Const YR = 2022
    Const SHT_COUNT = 19
    
    ' setup to generate testdata
    Call testSetup(RESFILE)
    
    Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet, wsRaw As Worksheet, arRaw
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As String
    Dim r As Long, c As Long
    Dim t0 As Single: t0 = Timer
    
    ' dictionaries
    Dim dictSht As Object, colSht As Collection
    Set dictSht = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Set colSht = New Collection
    
    ' build resource dictionary
    Dim arRes, dictRes As Object
    Set dictRes = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    arRes = GetResources(RESPATH & RESFILE)
    For i = 1 To UBound(arRes)
        dictRes.Add arRes(i, 2), arRes(i, 1)
    Next
      
    ' copy raw data to array
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set wsRaw = wb.Sheets(RAWDATA)
    With wsRaw
        r = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row
        c = .Cells(2, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        arRaw = .Range("A1").Resize(r, c).Value2
    End With
       
    ' create array for totals
    Dim arTotal(1 To SHT_COUNT), x As Long, y As Long, z As Long
     
    ' scan raw data once
    Dim n As Long, tmp
    For i = 3 To UBound(arRaw)
        ' clean data
        For j = 1 To UBound(arRaw, 2)
            If IsError(arRaw(i, j)) Then
                arRaw(i, j) = ""
            Else
                arRaw(i, j) = Trim(arRaw(i, j))
            End If
        Next
        
        ' sht name column D -
        k = arRaw(i, 4)
        If Len(k) > 0 And Not dictSht.Exists(k) Then
            n = n + 1
            dictSht.Add k, n
            colSht.Add Left(k, 5), CStr(k)
            
            'create array 254 x 26 for each sheet
            ReDim tmp(1 To 254, 1 To 26)
            arTotal(n) = tmp
        End If
        
        ' in year
        If arRaw(i, 5) = YR Then
            x = dictSht(k) ' sheet
            y = dictRes(arRaw(i, 10)) ' resource
            ' units cols 39 to 51
            For z = 1 To 13
                arTotal(x)(y, z) = arTotal(x)(y, z) + Val(arRaw(i, z + 38))
            Next
            ' costs cols 26 to 38
            For z = 14 To 26
                arTotal(x)(y, z) = arTotal(x)(y, z) + Val(arRaw(i, z + 12))
            Next
        End If
    Next
    
    ' create sheets in reverse order and add resource
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For i = colSht.Count To 1 Step -1
        Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add
        With ws
           .Name = colSht(i)
           .Columns("P:AO").Hidden = True
            ' resource
            .Range("B6").Resize(UBound(arRes), UBound(arRes, 2)) = arRes
            ' totals
            .Range("AP6").Resize(254, 26) = arTotal(i)
        End With
        ' add formating
        FormatSheet ws
    Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
    MsgBox "Totals completed in " & Format(Timer - t0, "0.0 secs"), vbInformation
     
End Sub

Function GetResources(f As String)
    
    Dim wb As Workbook, lastrow As Long, arRes, i As Long, j As Long
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(f, True, True) ' update links,read only
    With wb.Sheets(1)
        lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        arRes = .Range("A2:C" & lastrow)
    End With
    wb.Close SaveChanges:=False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
    For i = 1 To UBound(arRes)
        For j = 1 To 2
            arRes(i, j) = Trim(arRes(i, j))
        Next
        arRes(i, 3) = GL(i)
    Next
    'MsgBox i - 1 & " row read from " & FILENAME, vbInformation, FILEPATH

    GetResources = arRes

End Function

Function GL(i As Long) As String
    ' convert Resource to GL
    Select Case i
        Case Is > 254: GL = -1
        Case Is = 254: GL = 52752
        Case Is = 253: GL = 52723
        Case Is >= 246: GL = 52750
        Case Is >= 189: GL = 52723
        Case Is >= 90: GL = 52721
        Case Is >= 53: GL = 52732
        Case Is >= 27: GL = 52728
        Case Is >= 2: GL = 52725
        Case Is = 1: GL = 52734
    End Select
End Function

Sub FormatSheet(ws As Worksheet)

    Const YR = 2023

    'Headers
    Dim ar(1 To 1, 1 To 71), arMth, i As Long
    arMth = Split("Jul,Aug,Sep,Oct,Nov,Dec,Jan,Feb,Mar,Apr,May,Jun", ",")
       
    ar(1, 1) = "Year - Division - Low Org"
    ar(1, 2) = "Ref"
    ar(1, 3) = "Resource Unit"
    ar(1, 4) = "GL Account"
    ar(1, 5) = "Unit of Measure"
    ar(1, 6) = "Pricing"
    ar(1, 7) = "Resource Unit Fee"
    ar(1, 8) = "Full Year % Allocation"
    ar(1, 9) = "Units"
    ar(1, 10) = YR & " Units"
    ar(1, 11) = YR & " Amount"
    ar(1, 12) = YR - 1 & " Projected Units"
    ar(1, 13) = YR - 1 & " Projected Amount"
    ar(1, 14) = "Use"
    ar(1, 15) = "Usage"
    ar(1, 16) = "Next FY Units"
    For i = 0 To 11
        ar(1, i + 17) = arMth(i) & " Units" ' 17-28
        ar(1, i + 30) = arMth(i) & " $" ' 30-41
        ar(1, i + 43) = arMth(i) & " Units" ' 43-54
        ar(1, i + 56) = arMth(i) & " $" ' 56-67
    Next
    ar(1, 29) = "Next Fy $"
    ar(1, 42) = "Current Actuals YTD Units"
    ar(1, 55) = "Current Actuals YTD $"
    ar(1, 68) = "Current FY Budgeted Units"
    ar(1, 69) = "Current FY Budgeted $"
    ar(1, 70) = "Compare Units"
    ar(1, 71) = "Compare $"
    
    With ws
        .Range("A5") = ws.Name
        .Columns("AP:BB").NumberFormat = "0.00"
        .Columns("BC:BS").NumberFormat = "_($* #,##0.00_);_($* (#,##0.00);_($* ""-""??_);_(@_)"

        With .Range("A1:BS1")
            .Value2 = ar
            .Borders(xlEdgeBottom).Weight = xlThin
            .RowHeight = 45
        End With
        .Range("J1:M1").Interior.Color = RGB(226, 239, 218)
        .Columns.AutoFit
    End With
    
End Sub
```

Routine to generate test files

```vb
Sub testSetup(RESFILE As String)
   
    Const n = 5
    Const x = 19 ' sheets
    Const z = 254 ' resources
    
    Dim wb As Workbook, wbRes As Workbook, ws As Worksheet
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, m As Long, y As Long, r As Long
    Dim c As Long, nr As Long, t0: t0 = Timer
    nr = n * x * z
    
    ' delete existing sheets
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    On Error Resume Next
    For i = 1 To 19
        wb.Sheets("ID" & Format(i, "000")).Delete
    Next
    On Error GoTo 0
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    MsgBox "Existing sheets deleted", vbInformation, "Sheets deleted"
    
    ' generate resource file
    Set wbRes = Workbooks.Add(1)
    With wbRes.Sheets(1)
       For i = 1 To 254
          .Cells(i + 1, 1) = i
          .Cells(i + 1, 2) = "Res " & Format(i, "000")
       Next
    End With
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    wbRes.SaveAs RESFILE
    wbRes.Close
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    MsgBox RESFILE & " created", vbInformation, "Resource file"
      
    ' generate raw data
    Dim ar: ReDim ar(1 To nr, 1 To 64)
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    With wb.Sheets("CBK200 Raw Data")
        .Cells.Clear
        ' header
        For c = 1 To 71
           .Cells(2, c) = "Col " & c
        Next
    
        For y = 1 To n: For i = 1 To x: For j = 1 To z
            r = r + 1
            ar(r, 1) = "A" & r
            ar(r, 4) = "ID" & Format(i, "000") & " abcdefghi"
            ar(r, 5) = 2022
            ar(r, 10) = "Res " & Format(j, "000") ' Resource
            For c = 26 To 51
                ar(r, c) = Round(100 * Rnd(100), 2) 'c - 38 + y + i + j
            Next
        Next: Next: Next
        .Range("A3").Resize(UBound(ar), UBound(ar, 2)) = ar
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    MsgBox r & " rows generated in " & Format(Timer - t0, "0.0 secs"), vbInformation, "Rawdata"
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am confused on how you are calling the array with a 1d array. I see the collection, but I do not understand how it is referencing another array.

Comment: @billy `arTotal(1)` is itself an array of (254,26) elements. There are 19 of them ar(1) to ar(19), one for each sheet. The values for sheet 1 resource 1 column 1 are summated in `arTotal(1)(1, 1)`